# Rendering 1 random object from each collection

Tags: rendering

I am working on generative art and I need to set up my renders to render only 1 object per collection (a different one each frame) without having to do that manually. I am not very familiar with geometry nodes yet so I am not sure if it is possible this way. Another possibility that crossed my mind is an addon, but I haven't found anything useful.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: It's not really a thing for geometry nodes, and as far as I know, there are no existing add-ons, but there have been several questions here about it.  You might want to search for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not a complete specification of what you want or not 100 percent clear to me.  So I'll do an example for you to work with.  I'll assume you want a render of one object from each of several Collections per render file, and that you want all combinations.   I'll try to give pointers to a variation where you select an object at random from a Collection.

I would use a python script that first disables all objects from rendering and then varies what objects are render-enabled.

This may not be the simplest script, but is a variation on an existing script I have:

```
import bpy
import random

# constants
nCollections = len(bpy.data.collections)
frameCnt=0
filepathBase="//render/frame"
startFrameIdx=0
frameRenderCnt=999999

# set up a function to recurse through each collection
def renderCollection( collectionIdx, frameIdx: int, frameName ) -> int:
    if collectionIdx == (len(bpy.data.collections)):  # frame ready to render
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = frameName
        print('rendering', frameName)
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
        frameIdx += 1         
    else:
        # if you only want one random from each collection, replace 'for' loop with
        #obj = random.choice(bpy.data.collections[collectionIdx].objects)
        for obj in bpy.data.collections[collectionIdx].objects:
            obj.hide_render = False  # allow object to render
            tempFrameName = frameName + "_" + obj.name
            frameIdx:int = renderCollection( collectionIdx + 1, frameIdx, tempFrameName )  # march onward until rendered
            obj.hide_render = True  # prevent object render
            if ( frameIdx >= frameRenderCnt):
                return;
    return frameIdx


# INITIALIZE: prevent all objects from rendering
for coll in bpy.data.collections:
    for obj in coll.objects:
        obj.hide_render = True

# for each collection
total = renderCollection( 0, 0, filepathBase )
print( total, ' frames rendered' )
```

And a proof of concept:  (I'm getting the 'All uploaded files must be in the blend file format' 3.0 bug again from the upload site so...) here a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4z5jf135utqsvxt/nCollsRendered.blend?dl=0) to my Public DropBox example blend file.

Comment: Thank you, James, that's exactly what I want! However I have no coding experience so I can't adjust it to my specific needs. Could you PLEASE adjust it so I can render only certain range of frames at a time? 
I have a lot of objects in my collections and total number of renders would be over 10000, so running this script would freeze my PC forever.

Comment: @VáclavMusil -- demanding customer LOL!   Okay try what I updated in the script above.  For each run just change the `startFrameIdx` to the next group and `frameRenderCnt` to some more reasonnable number of frames to produce for each time.  So if `frameRenderCnt=10`, then run 1 `startFrameIdx=0` , then run 2 `startFrameIdx=10`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will save so much time because of you. Words cannot describe how thankful I am. <3

Comment: @VáclavMusil -- I work for credits: if you get the chance, click on the check mark on the top of my answer, so I will accumulate expert points, and an up-arrow if you haven't already.  thanks.